# Angular: How to stop select options box on input from appearing when I clear the contents?

Tags: css, angular, input, drop-down-menu

I wrote some simple logic in a reusuable component to clear the value of a select input when the "x" is clicked.

select.component.ts

```
  @Input() selectFormControlName: string;
  @Input() selectAbstractControl: AbstractControl;
...
  clearInput() {
    this.selectAbstractControl.patchValue("");
    this.selectAbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

Here's what it looks like before:

[image]

And here's what it looks like after I click the "X":

[image]

Is there a way to clear the contents without the select options opening up when doing so?

I was hoping it is just an HTML or CSS property, but I haven't found anything so far.

EDIT: Here is the full html for the select:

```
 <mat-select
      [formControlName]="selectFormControlName"
      (openedChange)="isActive = $event"
    >
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let selection of selectionData | async"
        [value]="valuePropertyName ? selection[valuePropertyName] : selection"
        (click)="toggleSingleOption()"
      >
        {{ selection[displayPropertyName] }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <button
      *ngIf="includeClearButton && selectAbstractControl.value"
      matSuffix
      mat-icon-button
      type="button"
      (click)="clearInput()"
      [tabindex]="tabIndex"
    >
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
```

And as far as the typescript logic, it's pretty much just the clearInput() method I have shown above.

I think it is default behavior of selects and autocompletes to launch the options dropdown when clicked anywhere within the input box.

I'm wondering if there is a way to override that behavior only in the case of the "x" that clears the form value.

Comment: I assume your click event also triggers the click on the select field. Can you provide the full code?

Comment: I have added more code example above.

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent the event bubbling with $event.stopPropagation()

```js
(click)="clearInput(); $event.stopPropagation()"
```